# QT: problem with creation of C++ library

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a C++ library with QT. However, when I launch the builder,
QT Creator asks me to provide an executable. I do not understand what it is really
asking for. Why would need an executable to make a library?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Perhaps it is asking you for the location of "qmake"? Have you set the QTDIR and QMAKESPEC environment variables?

Comment: What is the executable it is asking for ? Platform details etc. will be useful as well.

Comment: The only way qtcreator ask me an executable is when I run my librairy project not when I build it. Can you tell us more about the executable it is asking for?

Comment: @Giuseppe: you should post an answer describing what you did to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

To make a static library NAME, just collect your objects into an archive with

```
$ ar ru libNAME.a *.o
```

To make a shared library, it's

```
$ g++ OPTIONS -shared -o libNAME.so -Wl,-soname,NAME *.o
```

When you are linking a shared library with g++, you also need to give it any link OPTIONS that you would need for your program if you were linking an executable. For example, extra libraries (`-lm`), optimisation (`-O2`), pthreads (`-pthread`) or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is trying to launch an executable (which is normal if you are developing an application).

Instead of hitting "Run" or Ctrl+R, try to use "Build" or Ctrl+B. This should prevent Qt Creator from trying to launch your project.